# Position of gedolim on AI chatbots

Tags: rabbis, internet

I have heard that some gedolim have recently expressed special opposition to Artificial Intelligence (in contrast to whatever their attitudes are for internet in general). Which gedolim have spoken in opposition, and what exactly do they say?

Comment: I don't understand your mentioning the Internet. What's the connection?

Comment: @msh210 Some gedolim might say "internet is bad, so therefore AI is bad", and therefore we didn't learn anything about AI, so Michoel is trying to avoid ambiguities like that

Comment: The *kepeida*'s I have seen are not that AI is worse than anything else on the Internet, just that you shouldn't think it's better.

Comment: One of the issues with things like chatgpt is that there is a concern that it will lead to people drawing incorrect hashkofos - https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/2204647/25-leading-rabbanim-and-roshei-yeshiva-issue-ban-on-using-ai-chatbots.html

Comment: @RabbiKaii I don't get it. AI isn't on the Internet any more than word processors and Tetris are. Meaning, yeah, you can find them on the Internet, but you can also find them off the Internet and they have nothing intrinsically to do with the Internet. I don't understand why the Internet is mentioned in the question at all.

Comment: @msh210 It couldn't have happened without the internet, and indeed was inspired by the growth of the internet, it is hosted in the cloud, it is trained on what's being said on the internet, 99.9% of all AI consumers will exclusively use internet to access and use it...? That's why some might say "internet bad, so AI also bad", and we still don't know what they think of AI by itself

Comment: See, e.g., https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/2204647/25-leading-rabbanim-and-roshei-yeshiva-issue-ban-on-using-ai-chatbots.html.  "It is assur to connect with and use artificial intelligence chats, whether via a phone, text, or computer, even for a necessary use, and kal vachomer for divrei torah.”

Comment: ChatGPT is a small corner of the very large world of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence.  What about AI for medical, scientific and business uses?  What about when applied to robotics for firefighting and lifesaving opportunities? Perhaps the title of the question should be changed to "Position of gedolim on ChatGPT" or at least ""Position of gedolim on using AI to answer questions on halacha and hashkafa"".

Comment: @EraserX Doesn't seem to me that you are dealing with what they actually said.

Comment: @MichoelR from the links to the "kol koreis" I see on this page, what they said seems to be targeted specifically to AI chatbots (such as ChatGPT) but not AI in general, a term that has been around since 1956.  So the subject titled "Position of gedolim on AI" seems too broad. Some authors of certain kol koreis "against AI" that don't specify chatbots might not be fully familiar with the full meaning of what AI is.

Answer (score 6):

A whole raft of American-based Gedolei Yisroel* recently sign a kol koreh against things like chatGPT / chatbots (as seen [here](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/2204647/25-leading-rabbanim-and-roshei-yeshiva-issue-ban-on-using-ai-chatbots.html))

> In the kol koreh, the morei derech write that such chats have the ability to ingrain the wrong hashkafos in people, as well as outright kefirah, abominations, and other harmful content. It adds that those who begin using it are opening the door to being exposed to a veritable minefield of poisonous perspectives.
>
> “Therefore,” the 25 rabbanim and roshei yeshiva write, “it is assur to connect with and use artificial intelligence chats, whether via a phone, text, or computer, even for a necessary use, and kal vachomer for divrei torah.”
>
> The kol koreh states that this ban is applicable to all men, women, and children. It also exhorts parents and educators to bear the responsibility of warning their children and students against using AI chatbots.
>
> Importantly, the kol koreh notes that for those who need to use such chatbots in their business, “for the time being there is no solution on how to allow it,” but there will be future discussions on ways AI chatbots can be incorporated for business uses.

*The full list as follows:

- R' Elya Ber Wachtfogel, Rosh Yeshiva, Yeshiva of South Fallsberg
- [R' Elya Brudny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elya_Brudny)  Rosh Yeshiva, Mir Brooklyn
- [R' Malkiel Kotler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malkiel_Kotler), Rosh Yeshiva BMG
- R' Osher Eliyahu Kalmanowitz, Mir Brooklyn
- [R' Dovid Tzvi Schustal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovid_Schustal), Rosh Yeshiva, BMG
- R' Yosef Mermelstein, Rosh Yeshiva, Novominsk
- R' Yaakov Shraga Horowitz
- [R' Yaakov Bender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Bender), Rosh Yeshiva, Yeshiva Darchei Torah
- [R' Yitzchok Sorotzkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchok_Sorotzkin)
- [R' Yerucham Olshin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerucham_Olshin), Rosh Yeshiva, BMG
- R' Yisroel Dovid Erlich, Rosh Yeshiva, Yeshivas Mishkan Hatalmud of Lakewood
- [R' Yisroel Tzvi Neuman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisroel_Neuman), Rosh Yeshiva, BMG
- R' Refoel Scherer
- R' Shlomo Feivel Schustal, Rosh Yeshiva, Tiferes Yerachmiel of Lakewood

Admorim & Rabbonei Lakewood:

- R' Yaakov Ephraim Forscheimer, senior posek at Bais Medrash in Lakewood
- R' Shmuel Meir Katz
- R' Osher Chaim Lieberman
- [R' Simcha Bunim Cohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simcha_Bunim_Cohen)
- R' Mordechai Betzalel Klein
- R' Avraham Spitzer, Skver dayan of Lakewood
- R' Zvi Noach Portugal, the Skulen Rebbe
- R' Yaakov Yosef Twersky, Viznitz Rebbe of Lakewood
- R' Pinchas Wund (?)
- R' Tzvi Elimelech Herskowitz
- R' Shaul Simcha Friedman

[image]

The Skver Chassidus also came out against chat gpt in a kol koreh [here](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/2185224/ai-banned-skver-assurs-use-of-artificial-intelligence-tools-like-chatgpt.html) although at the time weren't yet sure as to the exact issues although they write:

> AI chatbots provide completely unfiltered access to apikorsus, lewd and perverse content, and all the issurim of “lo sasuru acharei levavchem,’ the kol koreh says.
>
> The use of AI chatbots is thus in the same category as the “issur hachamur” of using unfiltered internet, regardless of how the chatbot is used.
>
> “Therefore,” the letter says, “the use of AI is stricly prohibited in every way and form, even on a phone.”

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. The apikorsus I understand, but what are they referring to about the "lewd content"?

Comment: I imagine because you can ask it to generate non-kosher content. In chatgpt it would be in written form, but in things like AI image generators they can literally created yeish meiayen

Comment: @michoelr virtual girlfriends lo aleinu... What about FrumGPT?

Comment: some AIs generate images

Comment: I hear, but why is that a problem with my using it to code? My access doesn't include images.

Comment: לַפֶּ֖תַח חַטָּ֣את רֹבֵ֑ץ

Comment: This answer is thorough, so up vote, but where does it differentiate between AI and regular Internet? It even distinctly states that they are the same "prohibition".

Answer (score -3):

I asked ChatGPT

What are kosher animals. This is what it said:

---

In Judaism, the term "kosher" refers to food that is prepared in accordance with Jewish dietary laws outlined in the Torah, specifically in the books of Leviticus and Deuteronomy. Kosher dietary laws dictate what foods can and cannot be consumed, as well as how certain foods must be prepared and processed. When it comes to animals, there are specific criteria that must be met for them to be considered kosher. Here are some general guidelines:

```
Mammals:
    Land mammals must have cloven hooves and chew their cud to be considered kosher. Examples of kosher mammals include cows, sheep, and goats.
    Examples of non-kosher mammals include pigs and camels.

Birds:
    Kosher birds must be domesticated and not birds of prey. Examples include chickens, ducks, and turkeys.
    Birds like eagles and owls are generally not considered kosher.

Fish:
    Fish must have both fins and scales to be considered kosher. Examples include salmon, tuna, and haddock.
    Shellfish, such as shrimp and crab, are not considered kosher.

Insects and Reptiles:
    Insects are generally not considered kosher. However, there is limited mention of specific kosher locusts in the Torah.
    Reptiles are generally not considered kosher.

Slaughter and Processing:
    The method of slaughter, known as shechita, must be performed by a trained and observant Jew.
    The animal must be healthy and free from certain defects.
```

### It's important to note that these are general guidelines, and specific details may vary among different Jewish communities and interpretations. Additionally, the supervision of a qualified authority, such as a kosher certifying agency, is often required to ensure that the entire process, from raising the animals to processing and preparation, follows kosher standards.

I think that is a pretty good answer.

What does Shabbos observance mean?
ChatGPT

Shabbos observance, also known as Shabbat observance, refers to the practice of observing the Jewish Sabbath, known as Shabbat or Shabbos. Shabbat is a central and sacred day in Judaism, observed from Friday evening at sunset to Saturday evening at sunset. It is a day of rest, reflection, and spiritual enrichment.

Shabbat observance is based on the biblical commandment to "remember the Sabbath day and keep it holy," as outlined in the Ten Commandments. The observance of Shabbat involves a set of rituals, prohibitions, and positive commandments:

```
Candle Lighting: Shabbat is ushered in with the lighting of candles by the woman of the house, typically just before sunset on Friday evening. This marks the beginning of the Sabbath.

Kiddush: A blessing is recited over a cup of wine or grape juice to sanctify the Sabbath. This is done at the Friday night meal.

Blessing of Bread (Challah): A special blessing is recited over two loaves of bread, known as challah, during the Friday night meal.

Rest and Relaxation: Shabbat is a day of rest, and observant Jews refrain from work, business activities, and other forms of labor. Instead, the day is dedicated to prayer, study, family, and communal activities.

Synagogue Attendance: Observant Jews attend synagogue services, including Friday night services, Saturday morning services, and afternoon services.

Three Festive Meals: Traditionally, three festive meals are enjoyed on Shabbat: one on Friday night, one on Saturday morning, and one in the afternoon.

Prohibitions (Melachot): The observance of Shabbat involves refraining from specific activities known as melachot, which are traditionally associated with the construction of the Tabernacle in ancient times. These activities include things like kindling a fire, cooking, writing, and using electricity.
```

### Shabbat is a time for spiritual reflection, community engagement, and quality time with family and friends. Different Jewish denominations may have variations in the way Shabbat is observed, but the overall concept of a day of rest and holiness is central to all.

Not perfect. You say Kiddush on Friday night and Shabbos lunch. Nothing mentioned about Havdalah but over all not a bad answer.

---

User
What is Tefillin?
ChatGPT

Tefillin, also spelled phylacteries, are a set of small black leather boxes containing verses from the Torah (the Jewish sacred scripture). Jewish men, typically from the age of 13 and older, use tefillin during weekday morning prayers as a way to fulfill the biblical commandment to bind the words of God to their hands and foreheads.

There are two sets of tefillin—one for the arm (tefillin shel yad) and one for the head (tefillin shel rosh). Here's a brief overview of each:

```
Tefillin Shel Yad (Arm Tefillin):
    This box is strapped to the arm with leather straps.
    The box contains four compartments, each containing a parchment scroll inscribed with specific biblical verses: Exodus 13:1-10, Exodus 13:11-16, Deuteronomy 6:4-9, and Deuteronomy 11:13-21.
    The arm tefillin is placed on the weaker arm, usually the left arm, by right-handed individuals, and vice versa for left-handed individuals.

Tefillin Shel Rosh (Head Tefillin):
    This box is worn on the forehead, centered above the hairline.
    The box contains four compartments, each with a parchment scroll inscribed with the same verses as the arm tefillin.
    The tefillin is secured to the head with leather straps, and the knot is shaped like the Hebrew letter "dalet."
```

The commandment to wear tefillin is derived from several verses in the Torah, such as Deuteronomy 6:8: "And you shall bind these words as a sign upon your hands and between your eyes."

### Tefillin serve as a physical and tangible expression of one's devotion to God and a reminder of the commandments. The act of putting on tefillin is accompanied by specific prayers and rituals, and it is traditionally performed during the morning prayers on weekdays. It's important to note that tefillin are not worn on Shabbat (the Jewish Sabbath) or on Jewish holidays.

Not a bad answer.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: It doesnt answer the question